# Given sum and product, find the two variables

Tags: java, optimization, algorithm, mathematics

Basically, find x and y given the product = xy and sum = x + y. I would like review on optimization, clean code, and complexity.  It looks like O(1), but the `while` loop makes me wonder if it's something different.

```
/**
 *  x will always be less than or equal to y.
 */
final class Variables {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    Variables(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override public String toString()  {
        return " x = " + x + " y = " + y;
    }
}

/**
 * @author SERVICE-NOW\ameya.patil
 */
public final class SimultaneousEquations {

    private SimultaneousEquations () {}

    /**
     * Provided we dont have positive product and -ve sum, 
     * return value would be the smallest posive integer of the variable.
     * 
     * @param product : product of x and y
     * @param sum     : sum of x and y
     * @return        : smallest positive integer of x and y.
     */
    private static int getX(int product, int sum) {
        assert product != 0;
        assert product < 0 || (product > 0 && sum > 0);

        int x = 1;
        while (x*x != (sum * x  - product)) {
            x++;
        }
        return x;
    }

    /**
     * Given a product and a sum, return two variables.
     * 
     * @param sum       : sum of two variables
     * @param product   : product of two variables
     */
    public static Variables getVariables(int product, int sum) {
        if (product == 0) {
            if (sum < 0) {
                return new Variables(sum, 0);
            } else {
                return new Variables(0, sum);
            }
        }

        if (product < 0) {
            int x = getX(product, sum);
            return new Variables(product/x, x);
        }

        if (sum < 0) {
            int x = -getX(product, -sum);
            return new Variables(product/x, x);
        } 

        int x = getX(product, sum);
        return new Variables(x, product/x);
    }    


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 0 10
        Variables v1 = SimultaneousEquations.getVariables(0, 10);
        boolean result1 = v1.getX() == 0 && v1.getY() == 10;
        System.out.println(result1);

        // 2 5
        Variables v2 = SimultaneousEquations.getVariables(10, 7);
        boolean result2 = v2.getX() == 2 && v2.getY() == 5;
        System.out.println(result2);

        // -2 5
        Variables v3 = SimultaneousEquations.getVariables(-10, 3);
        boolean result3 = v3.getX() == -2 && v3.getY() == 5;
        System.out.println(result3);

        // 2 -5
        Variables v4 = SimultaneousEquations.getVariables(-10, -3);
        boolean result4 = v4.getX() == -5 && v4.getY() == 2;
        System.out.println(result4);

        // -2 -5
        Variables v5 = SimultaneousEquations.getVariables(10, -7);
        boolean result5 = v5.getX() == -5 && v5.getY() == -2;
        System.out.println(result5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Before we start guessing, lets solve the equations properly. We can substitute the equations so that we get `product = x · (sum - x) = -x² + sum·x ⇔ 0 = x² - sum·x + product`, with `y = sum - x`.

The equation can be solved by `x = sum/2 ± √(sum²/4 - product)` (see [*Reduced Quadratic Equation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Reduced_quadratic_equation)). Note that we get zero, one or two  distinct solutions. For example the special case of `product = 0` leads to `x = sum/2 ± sum/2 ⇒ {x = 0, x = sum}`. It is up to you if you pick a specific solution or output both. We have no solutions in ℝ when the expression inside the square root is negative. However, there would still be complex solutions.

Restricting yourself to integers only isn't valid, and will miss some solutions. Consider `product = 1, sum = 4`. This is solved by `x=3.73205, y=0.267949`.

Note that as this equation can be solved arithmetically, there is no need for guessing via loops.

---

Because you resort to guessing, your code contains various bugs, e.g. it will fail to handle parameters with no solution like `sum = 4, product = 5`. Instead, you will go into an unterminated loop.

When unit-testing your code, you should be using a proper test harness instead of  some test cases in a `main`. You might like *JUnit*. If you want to thoroughly test a method, do not only test a few simple cases:

- Explicitly test failure cases, e.g. parameters with no solution.
- Test especially large inputs to see if you correctly guarded against overflows (you didn't).
- Test random input (and record the seed!). It is easy to verify the correctness of the solution. This fuzzy testing may hit cases you didn't consider.
- Cover inputs around zero especially well, e.g. vary each parameter from `-2` to `2` by `0.5`-increments (after verifying manually that each parameter combination actually has a solution). Although this wouldn't hit another bug in your code, the combination `0, 0` is suspiciously absent. The combination `1, 0` would have exposed the bug that you don't handle inputs without solutions.

Comment: very useful input..